# Properly displaying UTF-8 chars in Perl

Tags: perl, utf-8

I am running perl 5, version 24, subversion 3 (v5.24.3) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
(with 1 registered patch, see perl -V for more detail)  (Active State).

Trying to parse HTML page encoded in UTF-8:

```
$request = new HTTP::Request('GET', $url);
$response = $ua->request($request);
$content = $response->content();
```

I parse the $content as one giant string using INDEX and SUBSTR functions, that works fine.
HTML page contains string with value ÖBB and I need to insert it in the database exactly as ÖBB
When I print it and insert in the db, instead of Ö I get some ascii characters.

NOTE: this question is not database related; MySQL handles utf-8 just fine, so if I insert value "ÖBB" it will take it no problem.

I've looked at great number of similar questions/answers here and in other forums and I am none wiser.

use utf-8 and binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8")  has not worked for me...
Would greatly appreciate a code snippet that would solve the issue, thank you.

Comment: How do you get that HTML page (string) into your program?

Comment: What database do you use? What driver? How do you connect to the database?

Comment: Consider using [utf8::all](https://metacpan.org/pod/utf8::all) which tries to make Perl as UTF8 friendly as possible.

Comment: When you say "print", do you mean print to console? In that case, make sure you have a the Unicode codepage active. Type `chcp` on the command line. If it says "65001", you're good in that regard. If not, type `chcp 65001` to activate the correct codepage.

Comment: Does your database configured to support UTF8? You did not indicate what database you use. If you use MYSQL DB then see the following [instruction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-applications.html). In case if you in MS Windows do not forget to change code page in terminal window `chcp 65001`.

Comment: Don't assume MySQL is "handling utf-8 just fine" just because it looks fine. DBD::mysql has a long history of UTF-8 handling bugs and is still inconsistent, you should use [DBD::MariaDB](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::MariaDB) which requires the connection charset of `utf8mb4` and handles Perl strings correctly (it still works for both MySQL and MariaDB).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked:

```
use Win32::API;
binmode(STDOUT, ":unix:utf8");
$SetConsoleOutputCP= new Win32::API( 'kernel32.dll', 
'SetConsoleOutputCP', 'N','N' );
$SetConsoleOutputCP->Call(65001);
```

All this was on the surface and I simply overlooked it ;-)

For MySQL db to work right and accept utf-8 encoded string this connection parameter had to be enabled:
    mysql_enable_utf8 => 1,

Comment: `binmode(STDOUT, ":unix:utf8");` is a bad version of `use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';`. // `mysql_enable_utf8 ` should be `mysql_enable_utf8mb4` // `SetConsoleOutputCP` is provided by Win32; no need to use Win32::API. (It's the equivalent of using aformentioned `chcp`)

Answer (score 1):

Decode inputs; encode outputs.

---

First of all, you don't decode your inputs.

`$response->content` returns the raw content that could be in any encoding. Use `$response->decoded_content();` to get the decoded response if it's HTML.

---

Second of all, you might not be encoding your outputs.

You didn't specify which database driver you use. Most DBI drivers have an option you need to specify. For example, with MySQL, you want

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect(
   'dbi:mysql:...',
   $user, $password,
   {
      mysql_enable_utf8mb4 => 1,
      ...
   },
);
```

---

You mentioned `use utf8;`. That tells Perl that your source code is encoded using UTF-8 rather than ASCII. Do use it if your source code is encoded using UTF-8.

This is not directly related to your issue.

---

You mentioned `binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8")`. That's a very poor way of writing

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```

The above handles that for STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR, and does so at compile time. It also sets the default for files open in scope of the pragma.

But that's assuming the terminal expects UTF-8. That would be the case if you used `chcp 65001`. For a version that handles whatever encoding the terminal expects, you can use the following:

```
BEGIN {
   require Win32;
   my $cie = "cp" . Win32::GetConsoleCP();
   my $coe = "cp" . Win32::GetConsoleOutputCP();
   my $ae  = "cp" . Win32::GetACP();

   binmode(STDIN,  ":encoding($cie)");
   binmode(STDOUT, ":encoding($coe)");
   binmode(STDERR, ":encoding($coe)");

   require open;
   "open"->import(":encoding($ae)");
}
```

[This](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1231890) has a few more details.

This is not directly related to your issue.

Answer (score -3):

There are several components are involved when you capture webpage and output it to the screen.

For the moment let's assume that you use Windows and run following script in a **terminal** window.

First you need to confirm that your terminal supports **UTF8** encoding. Type command `chcp` and see if it will output `65001`.

If it does then you set, if it does not then issue the following command `chcp 65001`.

Run the script with command `perl script_name.pl` and you should get output with `ÖBB` included in terminal window

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use utf8;
use feature 'say';

use HTTP::Tiny;

my $url = shift || 'https://www.thetrainline.com/en/train-companies/obb';

my $response = HTTP::Tiny->new->get($url);

if ($response->{success}) {
   my $html = $response->{content};

   $html =~ m/(<p>Planning.+pets.<\/p>)/;

   say $1;
}
```

To store data in **UTF8** encoding in **database**, the **database** should be configured to support **UTF8** encoding.

In case of **MYSQL** database the command should look like following

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb
  CHARACTER SET utf8
  COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

See the following **MYSQL** documentation [webpage](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-applications.html).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Using `chcp 65001` is not enough. You also need to use `use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';`

Comment: May be, but in my case it work just fine with settings I mentioned.

Comment: No it doesn't. It either prints garbage (`say chr(0xE9);`) or warns (`say chr(0x2660);`), It only works "fine" for strings that contain only ASCII characters, which is definitely not what the OP wants.

Comment: Please see two screenshots added to my answer: 1. terminal screenshot with output, 2. web browser window screenshot for same webpage

Comment: So you've just proven that you have have two bugs, then. 1) You didn't decode your inputs, and 2) you didn't encode your outputs. It happens to "work" because the web page is encoded using the same encoding as the terminal, but that's not always going to be the case.

Comment: Webpage is encoded UTF8 and terminal was switched to code page 65001 which is UTF8. The question was about UTF8 input and output, is it? Or you again have difficulty to understand the question?

Comment: The question is about UTF-8 *output*, regardless of the encoding of the input. Your assumption that all web pages use UTF-8 is incorrect.

Comment: OP did not asked how re-encode, he asked I get UTF8 and want to save UTF8 in database -- but you start to add something what was not required at all. The OP did not provide enough information how he retrieve the data (terminal type, code page set) -- I only could assume that his database may be not configured properly to accept UTF8 encoding, but again no information about database and it's configuration was provided.

Comment: Re "*but you start to add something what was not required at all*", I was commenting on *your* incorrect use of `say` and *your* mention of `chcp 65001`

Comment: If `say` prints what I expect then why would I need to convert encodings from one to another? So far I did not experience any problem may be except that I can not pass **cyrilic** arguments into perl script (you have explained what cause it). As I can read **cyrilic** from the file then I can use this approach when it will require. So far it works fine for me. NOTE: it is not even clear if the OP needs `say` at all -- he/she may be using **phpMyAdmin** for this purpose, he/she did not clarify about method of database access.

Comment: You should not assume the input and terminal or database output treat bytes the same way. You are dealing with text, so the correct procedure is to decode the bytes into characters (LWP does this for you when using decoded_content, otherwise you can use Encode), then configure the terminal or database driver to accept characters (by encoding them to UTF-8, but this is a detail of *that* implementation, not of the input).

Comment: It is impossible to consistently configure DBD::mysql to accept characters from Perl strings, but DBD::MariaDB sets the connection charset `utf8mb4` and handles Perl strings correctly by default, this is independent of the MySQL storage charset which determines what characters can be stored, and there you should also use `utf8mb4` not `utf8` which is a subset of UTF-8.